# How can I delete my account?

Tags: support

I looked into the profile settings and couldn't any button or option for account deletion.
I searched [on meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete%20account) and it seems no one asked this question before, can anyone help me?

should I contact a moderator for this ? thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I will ask why do you want to delete your account? Even if you no longer want to use the site you can still keep your account.

There is no way for a user (who has contributions) to delete their account on their own. You have to contact either SE, or a mod.
Ok, so if you *really* want to delete your account any mod (read me) can delete your account for you.
However it does not delete any of your posts, for good reason. You have helped a lot of people, SE does not want all that good stuff to just vanish.

This is what the message for "delete account" says:

> Deletes this user account, denormalizes identity on any posts they own, and deletes any negatively voted posts they own. Does not delete any content scored 0 or higher.

Which means any answer or question you have posted will no longer have your name on it (it will say user2816). Your profile page will be gone and if someone still has the url will return a 404.

Comment on my answer, and we can talk about your account deletion, or come by the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm)  and ping me.

Comment: i won't be using blender anymore , and lately BSE has become a distraction for me,I have a lot of work to do and I have to use other SE sites, but without realizing it I find myself here reading the BSE questions queue and trying to answer questions...
I thought about keeping it but that won't help since i'm still pingable and I still get notifications from here.
i'm okay with my posts not having my username,that's better inmyopinion. besides i can still answer as a guest if i change my mind.
and thanks for all your help:)!

Comment: Alright, sad to see you go. Thanks for all you have done on BSE: 97 answers, 5 questions, 157 votes, and 25 flags! I'll wait to delete your account till I hear back from you.

Comment: i enjoyed my 2 years here, u can delete:)

Comment: @root "This account is scheduled to be deleted in 23 hours," done.

Comment: thank u,sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No trouble at all. This is what we mod are here for, you the users.

Comment: Sad to see you go, but I understand your concerns now, I had no idea but BSE *can* be addictive in a very disturbing kind of way. Farewell and may we once day see you here again or at least using Blender