# Deleted Account takes my rep?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I saw that someone recently deleted there account and I didn't think much of it, until the next day when I noticed I was missing some rep. It wasn't a lot, only 15, but as just a beginner here at B.S.E. every point counts. So I read into it a little more and came across this:

> This removal occurs whenever a user is deleted, unless that user had a very high reputation score.

If I remember correctly the person who there account removed HAD a very high rep, so I'm sure other people were affected or am I just crazy?

> the staff use a special deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change for those who had been voted on by that user.

Ok I'm not trying to blame "the staff" here but I'm just curious is there ever a reason to *not* preserve the votes? It seems a little unfair to me.

But like some dead guy said

> Life isn't fair

Comment: The "dead guy" got me for 15 too.  If only he was a downvoter.

Comment: I don't think the dead guy uses blender stack exchange... or does he?

Comment: PS just checked and I lost 20.

Comment: I have lost 30... but points are not the point !... just **curiosity** for me... how to know on which questions or answers ?

Comment: ok... I have read that now http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: @lemon you can't. All up and down votes are completely private. Only the guys who play around in SE's database could find that.

Comment: I also lost about 60 points or so, but not really very concerned about it, just sad to see a good user go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(First off, I really like it when users research their own questions first. Nice going.)

This "unvoting" *may* seam unfair but when an account gets removed all votes cast (except in special cases) get removed too, both up and down.
So there actually are cases where you gain rep when a user gets removed.

Believe it or not, I'm actually not part of "the staff" and I don't have access to that special way of deleting a user and keeping the votes. It really is reversed for special cases. (Think something like gandalf3 permanently lost internet in Mordor and wanted his account gone, then the CMs would keep his votes.)

Removing votes cast, is just part of the normal part of when a user gets removed.

Thankfully it does not happen often.

PS if you are curious the user was root see [How can I delete my account?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/2217) for more info.

Comment: One more thing, root had very high rep, right? What is considered a "very high reputation" Or am I just remembering wrong?

Comment: very high reputation is relative to each site, and I don't even think there is a fixed about that the CMs will say "ok you have 10,001" rep we keep your votes." No, root did not have high rep, more then you but still not high.

Comment: I'll remember to bring Galadriel's phial of wifi next time I head that way.. thanks ;)